# how to break out of an if statement thats in a do while statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am making a game and i want the game to break after executing all the statements in the if statements after `score.setText(String.valueOf(gscore +""));` and continue the do while statement to do `gameplay()` again but how to I get the method to rerun after the `score.setText(String.valueOf(gscore +""));` part of the code is executed. a break; gives me an error.

```
protected void gamePlay(){
do{
    tgc.setY(tblc.getY());
    tbc.setY(tblc.getY());
    trc.setY(tblc.getY());
    tyc.setY(tblc.getY());


    x = (int)(Math.random()*(4) );

    if(x == 0){
        tbc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(x == 1){
        tgc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(x == 2){
        trc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(x == 3){
        tyc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    rLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(x == 0){

                if(tbc.getY() < bc.getY()+50 && tbc.getY() > bc.getY()-50){
                    gscore = gscore+1;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(gscore +""));

                }
                else{
                    gameLost();
                }
            }
            else if(x==1)
                if(tbc.getY() < gc.getY()+50 && tbc.getY() > gc.getY()-50){
                    gscore = gscore+1;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(gscore+"" ));

                }
                else{
                    gameLost();

                }
            else if(x==2)
                if(tbc.getY() < rc.getY()+50 && tbc.getY() > rc.getY()-50){
                    gscore = gscore+1;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(gscore +""));



                }
                else{
                    gameLost();

                }
            else if(x==3)
                if(tbc.getY() < yc.getY()+50 && tbc.getY() > yc.getY()-50){
                    gscore = gscore+1;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(gscore +""));



                }
                else{
                    gameLost();
                }
        }
    });
}while(checkGameLost()==false);
}
```

Comment: did you google first? did you find "break"

Comment: `a break; gives me an error` Explain the error.

Comment: you could call `gameLost()` instead of `break`.

Comment: yea but break doesn't work with if statements and i want the method to run again

Comment: error says break outside switch or loop and i want the method to run again from the beginning at that point not show game over.